# How to calculate standard deviation of event without knowing probability.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, standard-deviation

So, I've been bowling recently, and I realized I had an odd conundrum. I knew how to do binomial distributions with coin flips and whatnot, because we knew the probability.

However, when I tried to do strike chance analysis, I realized I was a bit lost.

For example, I bowled 5 games. I had 52 shots at all 10 pins, and 13 of those ended up as strikes. I know the total number of chances, and the number of successes, but since I don't know the actual probability of me getting a strike, I don't know how to find the standard deviation of my true strike rate.

If I had $A$ chances to strike, and striked $B$ times, I have a strike rate of $A/B$. Do I, for statistical purposes, presume that $A/B$ is the true probability? Or is there another formula for how to make estimates like that when the true probability is unknown, and I want to find the standard deviation of the true probability, and find the confidence intervals of my strike rate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model is that the number of strikes (successes) is a random
variable $X \sim Binom(n, p),$ with known $n = 52$ and unknown $p.$

The usual estimate of $p$ is $\hat p = X/n,$ where $X = 13$ is
the observed number of successes. As you point out, if you use the normal approximation to the binomial, you need
to know the SD of $\hat p$ in order to get a confidence interval 
for $p$. Of course, $Var(X) = np(1-p),$ so $Var(\hat p) = p(1-p)/n$
and $SD(\hat p) = \sqrt(p(1-p)/n.$ But we do not know $p$ so
we can't get an exact value for $SD(\hat p).$

The traditional 'Wald' 95% CI is of the form
$$\hat p \pm 1.96\sqrt{\hat p(1- \hat p)/n},$$
where we use an *estimated* value of $SD(\hat p).$

Recent studies have shown that this interval does not work well, particularly
for small $n$ because there are two approximations involved: normal to
binomial and $\hat p$ to $p.$ Specifically, the Wald CI does not have
the 'advertised' 95% coverage probability, especially for certain values of $p.$

A better procedure, due to Agresti and Coull, uses $\tilde n = n+4$ and $\tilde p = (X+2)/(n + 4)$  to get a 95% CI of the form

$$\tilde p \pm 1.96\sqrt{\tilde p(1- \tilde p)/\tilde n},$$
which performs much better. For your data this 95% CI is $(0.152, 0.384).$
As is typical of binomial CIs based on small $n$, this interval is quite wide.
For example, it takes about $n = 2500$ to estimate $p$ within $\pm .02$.
And if you bowled that much, your $p$ might change!

My [Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1448233/the-derivation-of-the-wald-interval/1462021#1462021) to a related Question on this site goes into some detail
about the poor behavior of the Wald interval and other types of CIs beyond
the ones discussed here. Yet
[another Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1368941/current-applications-of-the-central-limit-theorem-for-binomial-distributions/1369175#1369175) mentions the use of a Bayesian interval estimate for $p.$

Comment: Thanks. This was extremely thorough and helpful.